# Why Lua package.loaded can't cache global table returned by module?

Tags: lua, zerobrane

From the Lua 5.1 reference manual:

> Once a loader is found, require calls the loader with a single
>   argument,    modname. If the loader returns any value, require assigns
>   the returned value to package.loaded[modname]. If the loader returns
>   no value and has not assigned any value to package.loaded[modname],
>   then require assigns true to this entry. In any case, require returns
>   the final value of package.loaded[modname]

In my opinion, it meas when you use require and success, `package.loaded[modname]` must have value no matter true or table which depend on loader function has return

so there is my test below

[image]

Where is my `package.loaded["test"]`? But when I change a line in test.lua

[image]

Here is my Lua interperter:

ZeroBraneStudioEduPack-1.40-win32/Project/Lua Interperter/Lua

Sorry my poor English

P.S.
Screenshots above are available at full resolution: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAqsE.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt5cd.png)

Comment: This appears to be a deficiency in the debugger. In both cases, package.loaded.test is set to m_test as you expect. The debugger, however, appears not to expand the same table more than once (probably as a safeguard against infinite recursion). When declared as a global, m_test already appears in _G so it is not expanded again.

Comment: thks a lot, i just print _G later then think it's ide problem, but not explore the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZeroBrane Studio limits the size of the content retrieved and shown in the Watch panel (as controlled by several [`debugger.*` settings](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-general-preferences#debugger)). In your case, referencing `_G` returns a large payload that pushes out some of the other content (it just happens to push different content out as the global variable is already listed in `_G`, that's why you see slightly different results).

Try adding the following as the second line in your script `package.loaded._G = nil` and you should see more elements shown and the results will be consistent between the two cases.

Comment: Paul, can you make the loading of data to be displayed "on demand" (that is, lazy) to load only data that is really needed?

Comment: thks, i just think it's ide problem then not explore the reason.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, the suggested "lazy" stack/watch expansion has been implemented in the current dev version and will be included in the next release.